# How to make row values the column names in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I have a table like this:

```
QUESTION ANSWER  ID
A        123A    001
B        22G     001
V        44D     001
B        23dd    002
A        t59d    002
V        kfo0    002
```

And all I want to do is make it look as follows:

```
ID  A     B     V
001 123A  22G   44D
002 t59d  23dd  kfo0
```

I know how to do this in R but I wanted to know how to do so in SQL/Snowflake. The number of questions is fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [PIVOT()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot.html) as suggested by [mrks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68641677/1352490) :

```
select * from cte pivot (MAX(ANSWER) for QUESTION in ('A','B','V'))
```

[image]

Copy|Paste|Run in Snowflake:

```
with CTE as (select 'A' QUESTION, '123A' ANSWER, '001' ID
 union select 'B' QUESTION, '22G' ANSWER, '001' ID
 union select 'V' QUESTION, '44D' ANSWER, '001' ID
 union select 'B' QUESTION, '23dd' ANSWER, '002' ID
 union select 'A' QUESTION, 't59d' ANSWER, '002' ID
 union select 'V' QUESTION, 'kfo0' ANSWER, '002' ID) 

select * from cte pivot (MAX(ANSWER) for QUESTION in ('A','B','V'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for the [PIVOT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot.html) function. It might not look like it, because you are not looking for an aggregation, but PIVOT needs to know how to handle duplicate values. You could use <s>`ANY_VALUE`</s> `MIN` or `MAX` as the aggregation function. Given that you have only one value per question/id pair, it doesn't matter which one you use.

Comment: The PIVOT() function supports the built-in aggregate functions AVG, COUNT, MAX, MIN, and SUM.  Where did you see ANY_VALUE? I can't find in doco and raises an error when I tried.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Given that you seem to know that you only have one value question/id pair, you can just use `min`/`max` with the same effect.

Comment: @mrks this makes sense i think? , could i see the code?

Comment: Adrian posted it in his answer: `select * from cte pivot (MAX(ANSWER) for QUESTION in ('A','B','V'))`

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH QUESTIONANSWER AS 
(
   SELECT
      'A' QUESTION,
      '123A' ANSWER,
      '001' ID 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
      'B' QUESTION,
      '22G' ANSWER,
      '001' ID 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
      'V' QUESTION,
      '44D' ANSWER,
      '001' ID 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
      'B' QUESTION,
      '23dd' ANSWER,
      '002' ID 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
      'A' QUESTION,
      't59d' ANSWER,
      '002' ID 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
      'V' QUESTION,
      'kfo0' ANSWER,
      '002' ID
)
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   QUESTIONANSWER PIVOT (MAX(ANSWER) FOR QUESTION IN 
   (
      'A',
      'B',
      'V'
   )
)AS PIVOTTABLE ( "ID", "A", "B", "V")
```

Please make sure you don't have a single quote in the column name. To avoid single quote use **""** in the column.

Comment: this does not work because it requires me to add all the answers to the table....

Comment: Sometime answering with just code is ok ... I'd recommend using the CODE SNIPPET so it's clearly seen as code and not text answering the question - this is especially useful where english is a second language.  Answers are also enhanced by referencing appropriate links to online docs -> in the case PIVOT() is useful.